# Firebase FireStore Abstracted function not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a working read rule in fireStore to check that a user is in the users array of the /accounts/{account} resource:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /accounts/{account} {
       allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.users;
    }

  }
}
```

In order to simplify the code and to use a function elsewhere to check user access based on a resource id, and following the information in this link: [Security Rules!  | Get to know Cloud Firestore #6 19:25](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&t=1165s) I have attempted to abstract the code:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   function hasUserAccess(account){
    return request.auth.token.email in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(account)).data.users;
   }
   
   match /accounts/{account} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && hasUserAccess(account);
   }

  }
}
```

So that when I want to cross-reference the access for related documents, I can call the function. Why does the abstracted version fail to work? It seems like it should be working correctly based on the youtube video.

Comment: Could you please tell if you are getting any errors?

Comment: the error is permission denied. I've worked out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, it seems I couldn't use the function within the collection the function was inspecting?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   function hasUserAccess(account){
    return request.auth.token.email in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(account)).data.users;
   }

   // You can't use the function within this match condition
   match /accounts/{account} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email in resource.data.users;
   }

   // You CAN use the function within this match condition as it isn't for the collection /accounts
   match /otherData/{account} {
     allow read: if request.auth != null && hasUserAccess(account)
   }
   

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [hasAny()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) to check if the users list of accounts contains the email passed.

Also note that you have to pass the **[request.auth.token.email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth)** in the function.

Please use the following code in order to see if the user exists in the field "users" of your other collection:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

   function hasUserAccess(account,email){
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(account)).data.users.hasAny([email]);
   }
   
   match /accounts/{account} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && hasUserAccess(account, request.auth.token.email);
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I've managed to figure it, think a quirk but possibly to force reduced cost